# Non-type variadic function templates in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I saw a [blog post](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2011/10/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c11.html) which used non-type variadic templates (currently not supported by gcc, only by clang).

```
template <class T, size_t... Dimensions>
struct MultiDimArray { /* ... */ };
```

The example in the post compiles fine but I failed to get it to work with function templates.

Can anyone help figuring out the correct syntax (if such exists)?

```
int max(int n) { return n; } // end condition

template <int... N> // replacing int... with typename... works
int max(int n, N... rest) // !! error: unknown type name 'N'
{
    int tmp = max(rest...);
    return n < tmp? tmp : n;
}

#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
   std::cout << max(3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 0) << std::endl;   
}
```

Comment: I thought a variadic `max` already exists in the standard library... but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @Kerrek `max` isn't the point it's just an example.

Comment: Do you want a *non-compile-time* function (i.e. `max(3,1,4,foo(),5,bar())` as opposed to `max<3,1,4,2,5,6>()`) that takes an arbitrary number of parameters, *all of the same type*? And which returns the maximum?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid, yes, I was looking for a non-compile-time function. I have since seen the errors of my ways thanks to the explanations from Konrad & Luc.

Comment: Wait, why do you say that gcc doesn't support this? Compiles fine with 4.9

Comment: @CoffeeandCode, still fails with IDE1 in GCC 4.9.2  http://ideone.com/MsCKey

Comment: Of course that code doesn't compile, it's not valid C++. I thought you meant the example from the blog post. That code should not compile using clang either.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are simply confusing type names and non-type names. What you want simply doesn’t work.

You *can* probably use variadic non-type templates in functions, but not as (non-template) arguments:

```
template <int N, int... Rest>
int max()
{
    int tmp = max<Rest...>();
    return N < tmp ? tmp : N;
}
```

```
std::cout << max<3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 0>() << std::endl;
```

… although I haven’t tested this and I’m not sure *how* this should work given that you need to have a partial specialisation as the base case. You could solve this by dispatching to a partially specialised struct:

```
template <int N, int... Rest>
struct max_t {
    static int const value = max_t<Rest...>::value > N ? max_t<Rest...>::value : N;
};

template <int N>
struct max_t<N> {
    static int const value = N;
};


template <int... NS>
int max()
{
    return max_t<NS...>::value;
}
```

This will work.

Comment: I'm not looking for a compile time function. By using `typename... N` we get the same behaviour since the parameters are eventually coerced to `int` (the first parameter to any overload of `max` is `int`) but it's (IMO) a bit less elegant, I would like to specify that _this function takes any number of a specific type_. One _could_ use `initializer_list` but then the call site would have to use curly braces.

Comment: @Motti Like my first paragraph says, what you want simply doesn’t work.

Comment: @Motti `template<int I> void foo(I i);` would be nonsensical. You need to understand that before going variadic.

Comment: @Motti: If you're not looking for a compile-time function, then you also aren't looking for non-type template parameters.  Non-type template parameters must be compile-time constant expressions.

Comment: @LucDanton when you put it like that it's obvious, variadic templates are messing with my intuition. Apparently I don't grok them yet.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Your first example gives me errors on compileonline.com

Comment: @mk1 Yes, thanks. There was a trivial mistake. Try again now.

Answer (score 18):

This will print out all elements, 
get max could be implemented similarly

```
template <int N>
void foo(){
  cout << N << endl;
}

template <int N, int M, int ... Rest>
void foo(){
  cout << N << endl;
  foo<M, Rest...>();
}


int main(){
  foo<1, 5, 7>();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like the way how you avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: @parker0203 Why does the primary template need three template arguments? I thought `template <int N, int ... Rest>foo(){ foo<Rest...>(); }` would suffice.

Comment: It's not suffice, that's why the M, N, rest...  are all necessary, MSVC 2017  spit out error when called with foo<1,2>();
error C2668: 'foo': ambiguous call to overloaded function
could be 'void foo<2,>(void)'
or       'void foo<2>(void)'

Answer (score 7):

Here are two ways of defining a variadic function template only accepting `int` parameters. The first one generates a hard-error when instantiated, the second uses SFINAE:

```
template<typename... T>
struct and_: std::true_type {};

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
struct and_
: std::integral_constant<
    bool
    , First::value && and_<Rest...>::value
> {};

template<typename... T>
void
foo(T... t)
{
    static_assert(
        and_<std::is_same<T, int>...>::value
        , "Invalid parameter was passed" );
    // ...
}

template<
    typename... T
    , typename = typename std::enable_if<
        and_<std::is_same<T, int>...>::value
    >::type
>
void
foo(T... t)
{
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, non-type template parameters aren't used here.

Comment: very interesting usage of templates. may have also few applications. :)

Comment: Good idea but this does not work in any version of GCC.

> error: redeclared with 2 template parameters
>
> note: previous declaration 'template<class ... T> struct and_' used 1
.

https://godbolt.org/g/cQDSA0

Answer (score 1):

Luc Danton's solution doesn't behave correctly with parameters which are not of type `int`, but can be implicitly converted to an `int`. Here's one which does:

```
template<typename T, typename U> struct first_type { typedef T type; };
template<typename T> int max_checked(T n) { return n; }
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Ts>
int max_checked(T1 n1, T2 n2, Ts ...ns)
{
  int maxRest = max_checked(n2, ns...);
  return n1 > maxRest ? n1 : maxRest;
}
template<typename ...T> auto max(T &&...t) ->
  decltype(max_checked<typename first_type<int, T>::type...>(t...))
{
  return max_checked<typename first_type<int, T>::type...>(t...);
}

struct S { operator int() { return 3; } };
int v = max(1, 2.0, S()); // v = 3.
```

Here, `max` forwards all arguments unchanged to `max_checked`, which takes the same number of arguments of type `int` (provided by performing a pack-expansion on the `first_type` template). The `decltype(...)` return type is used to apply SFINAE if any argument can't be converted to `int`.

Comment: the calls to Max_checked is ambiguous in the partial ordering of c++11.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could achieve variadic args in your `max` example such that it can take any number of arithmetic arguments:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct are_arithmetic{
    enum {
        value = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && are_arithmetic<Ts...>::value
    };
};

template<typename T>
struct are_arithmetic<T>{
    enum {
        value = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value
    };
};

template<typename Arg, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<Arg>::value>::type>
Arg max(Arg arg){
    return arg;
}

template<typename Arg, typename Arg1, typename ... Args, typename = typename std::enable_if<are_arithmetic<Arg, Arg1, Args...>::value>::type>
auto max(Arg arg, Arg1 arg1, Args ... args){
    auto max_rest = max(arg1, args...);
    return arg > max_rest ? arg : max_rest;
}

int main(){
    auto res = max(1.0, 2, 3.0f, 5, 7l);
}
```

This is good because it can take any numeric type and will return the maximum number by its original type rather than just `int`, too.

Comment: When I run this the type of `res` is `double` not `long`. Anyway I was trying to understand non-type templates parameters so while your solution is cool it wasn't what I was looking for. Thanks anyway. http://ideone.com/gUnoLp