# Not sure why I'm getting compilation error about std::size_t not containing a parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have this class here:

```
template<typename ClassType, std::size_t... Dims>
class MatrixCell {
private:
    std::vector<std::size_t> coordinateIndices_;
    ClassType data_;

public:
    MatrixCell() : coordinateIndices_{Dims...} {}

    //template<typename ClassType, std::size_t... Dims>
    void addItem( ClassType item, std::size_t... Dims) {
        if ( !checkIndex( Dims... ) ) {
            std::ostringstream strStream;
            strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " current index doesn't exist.";
            Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_ERROR );
            throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
        } else {
            data_ = item;
        }
    }

private:
    //template<typename ClassType, std::size_t... Dims>
    bool checkIndex( std::size_t... Dims ) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

And I'm getting this compiler error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FileTester, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Matrix.cpp
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\filetester\filetester\matrix.h(155): error C3543: 'std::size_t': does not contain a parameter pack
1>  c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\filetester\filetester\matrix.h(171): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'MatrixCell<ClassType,Dims...>' being compiled
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\filetester\filetester\matrix.h(168): error C3543: 'std::size_t': does not contain a parameter pack
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
};
```

I don't have a problem understanding the error code; I'm having a problem understanding what exactly is causing the error, and not sure what the appropriate syntax is to correct it where I have tried many things.

I have a similar class that compiles just fine shown here:

```
// DimensionPack & Helper Struct
struct MatrixDimensionOddOrEven {
    const unsigned int even_or_odd; 
    explicit MatrixDimensionOddOrEven( unsigned int odd_or_even ) : even_or_odd( test( odd_or_even ) ) {}

private:
    const unsigned int test( unsigned int value ) const {
        if ( value == 0 ) {
            std::ostringstream strStream;
            strStream << __FUNCTION__ << "invalid number: " << value << " must be >= 1.";
            Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_ERROR );
            throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
        }
        return ( ((value % 2) == 0) ? EVEN : ODD );
    }
}; typedef MatrixDimensionOddOrEven MatDimOddEven;

template <std::size_t... Dims>
class DimensionPack {
public:
    std::vector<std::size_t> dimensions;
    std::vector<unsigned int> even_or_odd;
    const std::size_t total_dimensions = sizeof...(Dims);
    const std::size_t total_elements = countElements();

public:
    DimensionPack() : dimensions{Dims...},
        even_or_odd{ MatrixDimensionOddOrEven{Dims}.even_or_odd...} {
    }

private:
    std::size_t countElements() {
        std::size_t val = 1; // Don't Init to 0 otherwise multiplication won't work here!
        for ( std::size_t n = 0; n < dimensions.size(); n++ ) {
            val *= dimensions.at( n );
        }
        return val;
    }
}; // DimensionPack
```

So a pointer in the right direction would be very useful, and will be very appreciated.

Comment: So... Is the question about c++11 or c++14? If you're including a tag for the specification, use only one.

Comment: @tambre either or... I'm using VS2015 so it shouldn't matter it's still about variadic templates and their parameter packs...

Comment: @tambre fixed it just left c++ as general

Comment: If the problem was resolved, please update your question or post your own answer so it can help others with a similar problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the `std::size_t... Dims` function argument. `Dims` is a set of constants. One instantiation of `MatrixCell` would be `MatrixCell<double, 2, 3, 4>`. `Dims...` would expand to `2,3,4`. What signature should `MatrixCell<double, 2, 3, 4>::addItem` have? Do you mean "want same number of `std::size_t` arguments as there are parameters in the `Dims` pack"?

Comment: The error says it all:  by the line `void addItem( ClassType item, std::size_t ... Dims)` you tell the compiler to unpack `size_t`, which simply doesn't work as it's no parameter pack. I guess you find the intended solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877293/non-type-variadic-function-templates-in-c11)

Answer (score 4):

You probably want this:

```
void addItem( ClassType item, decltype(Dims)... dims ) {
    if ( !checkIndex( dims... ) ) {
```

and

```
bool checkIndex( decltype(Dims)... dims ) {
```

Unfortunately VC++ can't compile this. It is probably a compiler defect (not quite sure as I didn't try to verify this against the standard, but both g++ and clang compile it). Fortunately we can work around it. We don't really need `decltype`, we need something that takes an `std::size_t` constant-expression, ignores it and returns `std::size_t`. Something like a constant type-level function. For example:

```
template <std::size_t>
struct const_size_t
{
    using type = std::size_t;
};
```

and use it like this:

```
void addItem( ClassType item, typename const_size_t<Dims>::type... dims)
```

[Live demo](http://rextester.com/OXQM26187)

Comment: I like your answer however when I tried that I'm getting this: `matrix.h(154): error C3543: 'unknown-type': does not contain a parameter pack
matrix.h(170): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'MatrixCell<ClassType,Dims...>' being compiled
matrix.h(167): error C3543: 'unknown-type': does not contain a parameter pack`

Comment: (...continued) I even tried to declare the member functions as a template function and still generates same compiler error.

Comment: @FrancisCugler It compiles with gcc and clang, must be a vc++ defect. You can work around it, see http://rextester.com/OXQM26187