# C3543 "does not contain a parameter pack" when using variadics on stream buffer

Tags: c++, stream

I want to mimic the Linux `tee` command with multiple streams. To achieve that, I implemented a `streambuf` first:

```cpp
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

template<std::streambuf*... Buffers>
class teebuf : public std::streambuf
{
private:
    std::vector<std::streambuf*> buffers;
    void add_all(std::streambuf* buffer, std::streambuf*... buffers)
    {
        this.buffers.push_back(buffer);
        add_all(buffers...);
    }
public:
    teebuf(std::streambuf*... buffers)
    {
        add_all(buffers);
    }

    // other implementation not needed
};

int main()
{
    std::stringstream s;
    teebuf tee(s.rdbuf(), std::cout.rdbuf());
}
```

However, the class won't compile and the error message is

> error C3543: 'std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits> *': does not contain a parameter pack

in line 11 (`add_all()`) and line 17 (`teebuf()` constructor).

I've tried following [this suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c-compilation-bug-parameter-pack-in-constructor-wi/1203865) by declaring a `using HelperType = typename std::streambuf*;` and then using it, but there's no difference.

I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043215/not-sure-why-im-getting-compilation-error-about-stdsize-t-not-containing-a-pa) so I declared a struct

```cpp
template<std::streambuf*>
struct HelperType
{
    using type = typename std::streambuf*;
};
```

and used it like

```cpp
void add_all(std::streambuf* buffer, typename HelperType<std::streambuf*>::type... buffers)
[...]
teebuf(typename HelperType<std::streambuf*>::type... buffers)
```

but that just results in more errors.

How do I get this compiled?

I'm using VS 2022 with C++ 17.

Comment: Move `...` after parameter names in usages.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with unused non-type template parameters? You seem to want the templated constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what the class template parameter pack was going to be used for so I skipped that. You could add your buffers by making `add_all` and the `teebufs` constructor into function templates:

```cpp
class teebuf : public std::streambuf {
private:
    std::vector<std::streambuf*> buffers;

    template <class... Bufs>
    void add_all(std::streambuf* buffer, Bufs... bufs) {
        buffers.push_back(buffer);
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Bufs) > 0) add_all(bufs...);
    }

public:
    template <class... Bufs>
    teebuf(Bufs... bufs) {
        add_all(bufs...);
    }
};
```